# How can I solve NoSuchMethodError using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit

I tested some example code but Retrofit Builder occured error.
I can check for errors in initialization.

I read two articles but no my case.
[Retrofit2 NoSuchMethodError with external AAR that uses OkHttp3 3.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572791/retrofit2-nosuchmethoderror-with-external-aar-that-uses-okhttp3-3-3-1)

[Unit testing: NoSuchMethodError at mock retrofit get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001404/unit-testing-nosuchmethoderror-at-mock-retrofit-get-request)

Looking at other articles, the same error occurs in certain methods.
But in my case it happens in initialization.

Creating a new project, just adding retrofits causes the same problem.

my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    viewBinding.enabled = true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kr.ac.sunmoon.gijoe.camaps"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    // Mistake, missing lines, Start
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    // missing lines, End
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

my error code:

```
public class .... {
    private Retrofit mRetrofit;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRetrofitinit();
    }

    private void setRetrofitInit() {
        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(getString(R.string.baseUrl))  <== Error: noSuchMethodError
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    }
}
```

and Error Messages:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kr.ac.sunmoon.kiwoon.testretrofit, PID: 10254
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Util.java:321)
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1313)
        at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:506)
        at kr.ac.sunmoon.kiwoon.testretrofit.MainActivity.setRetrofitinit(MainActivity.java:28)
        at kr.ac.sunmoon.kiwoon.testretrofit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Have you added both the dependencies?`//Retrofit & OkHttp
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'

    // JSON Converter
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'`

Comment: @SairajSawant Oh, My Mistake. but after add two line, same error. I used it //implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
//implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

Comment: `getString(R.string.baseUrl)` is this not null?

Comment: @SairajSawant Yes, ```getString``` is not null. And when I typed directly URL, same error too. I don't know why this error is occurred.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59448917/6763544 should fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59448917/6763544) :

```
android {

    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```